# SubmitChanges not working with WCF RIA and POCO Child Objects

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a Parent POCO class `ParentItem` with a `List<ChildItem>` inside it and i have set the correct AssociationAttribute. But when i am trying to add a `ChildItem` to the `ParentItem` using `ParentItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem)`, the domainContext's `HasChanges` is true, but `DomainContext.SubmitChanges` is not working.

I checked the `HasError` property and there are no errors, but its not calling the `Insert` or `Update` operations. It works fine if i change any other property of the `ParentItem`.

I am using Silverlight 5.0, WCF RIA SP1 and EF 4.0, and i am not sure what i am doing wrong!

**UPDATE**

I replaced the SubmitChanges with an Invoke method and found out that at the server side i am not getting the children. The children count is zero. Does that means my association is wrong?

This is my structure

```
public class ParentItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentId{get;set;}

    [Include]
    [Association("ChildrentItems", "ParentId", "ParentId")]
    public List<ChildItem> Children{get;set;}
}

public class ChildItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildItemId{get;set;}
    public int ParentId{get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `[Composition]` attribute, you are instructing WCF RIA to track changes to the collection within Silverlight and publish the deltas to the server on `DomainContext.SubmitChanges`.

```
public class ParentItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentId{get;set;}

    [Include]
    [Association("ChildrentItems", "ParentId", "ParentId")]
    [Composition]
    public List<ChildItem> Children{get;set;}
}
```