# Sending Child Collections with an Invoke and WCF RIA

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

We have a very complex Save method where we call an Invoke method which we pass 2 List of Entites as parameters.Everything was working fine so far. Now we have to make a change to the save method and i need to add a List of different entities as the third parameter.

This is how the new entity looks like.

```
public class WorkItem{

[Key]
public int WorkItemId {get;set;}
[Include]
[Association("WorkItems", "WorkItemId","WorkItemId")]
public List<WorkItemChild> WorkItemChildren {get;set;}

 }

public class WorkItemChild{

[Key]
public int WorkItemChildId {get;set;}
public int WorkItemId {get;set;} 
public string WorkItemdescr{get;set;}

}
```

I am trying to send `List<WorkItem>` as a third parameter to Invoke Save method,  but on the server side the collection WorkItemChildren  is always zero.What am i doing wrong ?

Can i not use Invoke method to send children to the server ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SubmitChanges not working with WCF RIA and POCO Child Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509852/submitchanges-not-working-with-wcf-ria-and-poco-child-objects)